# GC overhead limit exceeded container killed in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, garbage-collection, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am executing 13 table map join on our development environment in hadoop 2 cluster using YARN.All the table join as LEFT OUTER with main table .Total number of there 15 join join.

Since most of the small table are less than 200-300 MBs,so I used USING 'replicated' to execute the script code.It executes quite fast but get stuck past 95-99% .When I check the application url ,2 reducers failed throwing error as "
GC overhead limit exceeded container killed by the ApplicationMaster.Container killed on request.Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143".

Other reducer failed with error Timed out after 300 secs Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.Container killed on request.Exit code is 143..

Comment: Dear Abid, have you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak the values directly from within your pig.

In your Application URL, check the job properties, and see the current values of

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb   
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
mapreduce.map.java.opts
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb
```

You can begin tweaking by raising the values of the properties by 512 at a time. However, do not raise the value of mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb over 756.

To change the values directly from pig, at the top of your pig, before any code, add the properties as follows :

```
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb    3072;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 3072;
set mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx2764m;
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts -Xmx2764m;
set mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb 756;
```

The above are the properties that worked for me for a data-set of similar size as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either increase the size of YARN container by setting `mapreduce.map.java.opts` and `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`. In my environment biggest size of YARN container is 32GB so I add `-Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx30000m` and `-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=32000` when kicking off streaming jar or else from oozie:

```
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
 <value>-Xmx30000m</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
 <value>32000</value>
</property>
```

or else you need to get rid of map join. In Hive I do it by `set auto.convert.join=FALSE;`

Comment: In one of the threads I found ,it was mentioned to increase the heap size for data node in HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS file  xport HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Xmx10g .his will set the heap to 10gb...you can increase as per your need.

You can also paste this at the start in $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hadoop-env.sh file . is that any one of the thing can work?

Comment: Also,its failing only on 2 reducers,can we just increase the memory size for reducer only ,instead of doing for mapper as well.

Comment: As you mentioned map join so I suggested map only related settings. For reducers you will need `-Dmapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx30000m` and `-Dmapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=32000`